# Styling ActionBar dropdown menu

Tags: android, android-theme

I'm using a custom theme that inherits from `DarkActionBar` and I want to customize dropdown menu to be white like when using Light Holo theme.

I've been able to change the background to white using:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyDropDownNav</item>
</style>
<style name="MyDropDownNav">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_white</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_whyite</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_white</item>
</style>
```

But I haven't any clue of how to change the text color to black. Because after setting white drawable the problem is that text isn't visible because is white on white background.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I answer myself after some investigation.
In addition to question's styling you need to:

- Customize `android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle` for `actionBarWidgetTheme` changing it's text appearance.
- Also don't forget that dropdown list is managed by the adapter you use. Then if you used the standard one (`simple_dropdown_item_1line`) there's no problem. But if you used a custom one like me (to be able to add an icon) **don't forget to apply** `style="?attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"` in your layout TextView.

Then final custom style is:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<style name="Theme.myapp" parent="@style/Theme.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/myapp_DropDownNav</item>        
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/myapp.actionBarWidgetTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="myapp.actionBarWidgetTheme" parent="@style/Theme.">
     <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/myapp.Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner</item>
</style>

<style name="myapp_DropDownNav" parent="@style/Widget.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_myapp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_myapp</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_myapp</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_myapp</item>
</style>

<style name="myapp.Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner" parent="Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/myapp.TextAppearance.Widget.DropDownItem</item>
</style>

<style name="myapp.TextAppearance.Widget.DropDownItem" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.DropDownItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Where drawables in `myapp_DropDownNav` are white background ones that you can generate with [ActionBar Style generator](http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) in [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html)

Comment: Can't have @style/Theme. as a parent it shows red in IDE.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting [`itemTextAppearance`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#itemTextAppearance). That should achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I have stumbled on what may be the simplest way to do this. I was working with the AppCompat library.

```
<style name="ApplicationTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light</item>
    <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Excelent! But I think it will only work with Light.DarkActionBar themes.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to simply inherit from the Sherlock.Light theme and change the applicable fields to the Dark values. For my app, we wanted a white "up" icon, and white text for the action labels. I don't provide dark versions of my actionbar icons, so they are all white anyway. So after several hours messing around with it and following different people's suggestions, I finally found what I was looking for in the ABS themes file.

I inherit from Sherlock.Light (well, technically HoloEverywhereLight.Sherlock but...) and change:

```
<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/White</item>
<item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/White</item>
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/abs__ic_ab_back_holo_dark</item>
<item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/abs__ic_ab_back_holo_dark</item>
<item name="android:dividerVertical">@drawable/abs__list_divider_holo_dark</item>
<item name="dividerVertical">@drawable/abs__list_divider_holo_dark</item>
```

That's it. It's way simpler and easier than trying to extend classes, restyle things in code, etc.