# How to style the ShareIntent action menu

Tags: android, android-menu

I am trying to change the background black to some other color (default, hover, lost focused) using XML styles:

[image]

I was able to change around the overflow menu option but not sure which XML attribute I have to use for the `ShareIntent` action provider menu.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know [this](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator)?
And you already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11483149/1989579) or [this](http://www.silverbaytech.com/2013/05/20/themes-for-the-android-actionbar-drop-downs/) ?
I hope it's useful.

Comment: `this` is only for default menu and not ShareIntent menu :/