# Change style of specific item in drop-down

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-actionbar

I have drop-down in action bar with different categories and I want highlight some categories.
How can I make bold text of specific item of drop-down?

Comment: try to add styles by the drop down id in the styles.xml or look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11483149/3164682

Comment: For example, I want make bold text of only item in 4 position in drop down

Answer (score 0):

```
Spanned text = Html.fromHtml("<b>bold text</b>");
submenu.add(0, 4, 0, text).setIcon(R.drawable.top_menu_settings_icon);
```

I hope this code will help you to achieve your purpose.